# How to convert "top 10" list from SQL to NoSQL

Tags: mysql, nosql, redis, ranking

I have an online game currently using MySQL. I have a Player table looking like this:

```
create table player (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    score integer
);
```

I have an index on "score" column and display the rankings like this:

```
select id, name, score from player order by score desc limit 100
```

I'd like to migrate my system to Redis (or, if some other NoSQL is more applicable to this kind of problem, please tell). So I wonder what is the way to display this kind of rankings table efficiently?

AFAICT, this could be a Map/Reduce job? I know next to nothing about Map/Reduce although I read some docs I still don't quite understand as I haven't been able to find any real-life examples.

Can someone please give me a rought example how to do the above query in Redis?

Comment: you could consider orientDB (a noSQL derivat, quite nicely designed) http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/SQLQuery . They offer a LIMIT command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In redis you can use Sorted sets ( http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set ) 
When you have scored items in sorted set you can get top N by invoke `ZRANGE players 0 N`

Comment: Looks good. One question: If I need to have multiple rankings (say: score and monthly_score), would I need to create two sets?

Comment: yes, for each score. Or if monthly_score depends from score, I think you can use *list* for each player to star his score history

Answer (score 1):

Good question - In MongoDB you would have to use the group() function to return this type of query:

```
select id, name, score from player order by score desc limit 100
```

Might look something like this:

```
db.player.group(
           {key: { id:true, name:true },
            reduce: function(obj,prev) { if(prev.cmax<obj.score) prev.cmax = obj.score; },
            initial: { cmax: 0 } // some initial value
            });
```

Using a MapReduce based approach is probably best, see:

- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group
- http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/finding_max_and_min_values_for_a_key/

Comment: Thanks. How efficient would such function be? I have about 10 million records in that Player table. Will it have to traverse all records in Map process?

Comment: Well, yes in this case it does have to traverse the entire dataset. I think that the best solution might be to filter your dataset first before MapReduce  - for example, start with all players with a score over "50" or something. Otherwise, the 'efficiency' will always be the same, but the speed depends on the system you are using - if you have your NoSQL distributed across multiple machines, the Map and Reduce can take place across the various servers on the network.